# Import Python 2.7 code into C++ programs on Mac

Tags: python, c++, gcc, g++

I want to use Python code in C++ programs. My IDE is Mac Eclipse C++.

I have a cpp file CppTest.cpp importing a .py file.

CppTest.cpp has `#include <Python.h>`.

I put python2.7 folder in GCC C++ Compiler include paths.

It is like:

```
g++ -
I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7...
```

But the cpp does not run. The C++ linker seems naive.

What can I do?

Full console info is:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/CppTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/CppTest.d" -MT"src/CppTest.o" -o "src/CppTest.o" "../src/CppTest.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/CppTest.cpp

Building target: CppTest
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "CppTest"  ./src/CppTest.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyInt_AsLong", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyInt_FromLong", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_PyTuple_SetItem", referenced from:
      great_function_from_python(int) in CppTest.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in CppTest.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in CppTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [CppTest] Error 1

16:37:09 Build Finished (took 558ms)
```

Comment: I only have a .py file in my project. In the folder where Python is installed, I have no idea about the .so file.

Comment: Are you sure you are not picking-up Python 3 components?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755303/undefined-reference-to-pystring-fromstring

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems

Comment: Thanks. The new makefile parameters are good. Eclipse cannot automatically generate a good makefile.